Why was Telmar unpeopled and Narnia in disorder?
Near the end of Prince Caspian, Aslan tells the story of Caspian's ancestors and how the Telmarines came to Narnia. The original ancestors were pirates in our world, who settled on a South Sea island and found a way into the world of Narnia, but not directly into the nation of Narnia but rather the land of Telmar:

And so they fell, or rose, or blundered, or dropped right through, and found themselves in this world, in the Land of Telmar which was then unpeopled. But why it was unpeopled is a long story: I will not tell it now. And in Telmar their descendants lived and became a fierce and proud people; and after many generations there was a famine in Telmar and they invaded Narnia, which was then in some disorder (but that also would be a long story), and conquered it and ruled it.

The location of Telmar is shown in a map which was posted by Greenonline in an answer on another site; I'm not sure of the canonicity of this map, or whether it's just fan art, but that would be a separate question. My question here is: although Aslan fobs off the questions of Telmar's emptiness and Narnia's disorder with "that's another story and shall be told another time", is there any further info on this anywhere else within the Narnia canon? Either in other books of the series, or extratextual information from the author - anything from which any details of a possible explanation can be deduced? Do we know why the incomers found Telmar empty, or why later Narnia was in such disorder that they could easily conquer it?

Walter Hooper's book Past Watchful Dragons: The Narnian Chronicles of C. S. Lewis (Collier Books, 1971) includes a timeline that he claims was given to him by Lewis himself. That document has been reproduced in other related works, under the title "An Outline of Narnian history so far as it is known". It was compiled after the publication of all seven Narnia books and is mostly consistent with the history presented in them.
It includes the following events (the years are years since the creation of Narnia):

In 204, "Certain outlaws from Archenland fly across the Southern desert and set up the new kingdom of Calormen."
By 300, "The empire of Calormen spreads mightily. Calormenes colonise the land of Telmar to the West of Narnia."
But then in 302, "The Calormenes in Telmar behave very wickedly and Aslan turns them into dumb beasts. The country lies waste."
It is that way until 460, when "Pirates from our world take possession of Telmar."

The Pevensies arrive in 1000, after Jadis has ruled for a century of winter. The conquest of Narnia by Telmar is dated to 1998, with the events of Prince Caspian taking place in 2303. There is no further background here about disorder in Narnia itself.
This is as close to an authoritative account as we are likely to get. The books themselves have nothing more to say about Telmar's history than is already described.  I would also speculate that in the timeline, Lewis is trying to "fit" the original Telmar into the history in a way that doesn't create too many more problems: so it is founded from Calormen (not another invented nation), and disposed of many centuries before Prince Caspian (long enough for people to forget the whole pirate thing).
The motif of regression to a non-Talking beast comes up several times in the series, especially The Last Battle. Another question on this site, Is there any deeper significance to Lucy's thought of what if "men started going wild inside" in our world?, deals with Lucy's question from Prince Caspian,

Wouldn't it be dreadful if some day, in our own world, at home, men started going wild inside, like the animals here, and still looked like men, so that you'd never know which were which?

As pointed out in an answer there, Lewis's That Hideous Strength (1945) also treats the topic of people becoming inhuman; the character of Wither, for example, runs his mind mostly on autopilot. His own selfhood decays and language itself is ultimately taken away from him and his allies, as the "curse of Babel" leads him to give an after-dinner speech:

Tidies and fugelmen - I sheel for that we all - er - most steeply rebut the defensible, though, I trust, lavatory Aspasia which gleams to have selected our redeemed inspector this deceiving. It would - ah - be shark, very shark from anyone's debenture...

Equally, his colleague Frost has removed himself from cognition in a different way:

Increasingly, his actions had been without motive. He did this and that, he said thus and thus, and did not know why. His mind was a mere spectator.

And in this way he ends up watching his body immolating itself (under the influence of the dark eldila) without intervening or protesting.
In relation to Telmar, it seems that Lewis returned to the theme of the removal of human traits, as a standard weapon in the divine arsenal. Being turned into an animal is also a common mythological punishment (Homer, Ovid, etc.) as well as one that possibly comes up in the Bible,

The same hour was the thing fulfilled upon Nebuchadnezzar: and he was driven from men, and did eat grass as oxen, and his body was wet with the dew of heaven, till his hairs were grown like eagles' feathers, and his nails like birds' claws. (Daniel 4:33, KJV)

It's unclear how literal this is meant to be, but Nebuchadnezzar certainly has his "understanding" or "reason", Hebrew מַנְדַּע, taken away for the duration. The whole episode is a punishment for his pride in the empire of Babylon and to show the vastly superior power of God.

Thanks, great answer! I wonder what's meant by "turns them into dumb beasts" - if that means a literal physical change from human to animal form, or just a change like the Cat in The Last Battle, from intelligent sentient beings to mindless brutes. Is there any precedent for the former within the Narnia series? I vaguely seem to recall some particularly obnoxious human being turned into an animal (possibly in The Horse and His Boy?), but not sure.

Yes, THAHB has Rabadash turning into a donkey (non-talking, but does understand Aslan's speech) and then later back into a donkey-eared human.

The nasty schoolboys were turned into pigs at the end of Prince Caspian. The "turning into animals" also echos the Curdie stories (which Lewis knew and appreciated) where Curdie could tell what beast a person was turning into.
